# Binding source thread in PLINQ

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I have a a computation that I'm parallelizing using PLINQ as follows:

- Source `IEnumerable<T> source` is providing objects read from a
  file.
- I have a heavyweight computation `HeavyComputation` I need to do on
  each `T`, and I want these farmed out across threads, so I am
  using PLINQ like: `AsParallel().Select(HeavyComputation)`

Here's where it gets interesting: due to constraints on the file
reader type that provides the `source`, I need `source` to be
enumerated on the initial thread, not on the parallel workers. I need
the full evaluation of the `source` to be *bound* to the main
thread. However it seems the source is actually enumerated on worker
threads.

My question is: Is there a straightforward way to modify this code to
bind the enumeration of the `source` to the initial thread, while
farming out the heavy work to the parallel workers?  Keep in mind that
just doing an eager `.ToList()` before the `AsParallel()` is not an option here,
as the data stream coming from the file is massive.

Here is some example code that demonstrates the problem as I see it:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class PlinqTest
{
    private static string FormatItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
            return String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(";", source));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var expectedThreadIds = new[] { Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId };

        var threadIds = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
                .Select(x => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) // (1)
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(8)
                .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
                .AsOrdered()
                .Select(x => x)                                    // (2)
                .ToArray();

        // In the computation above, the lambda in (1) is a
        // stand in for the file-reading operation that we
        // want to be bound to the main thread, while the
        // lambda in (2) is a stand-in for the "expensive
        // computation" that we want to be farmed out to the
        // parallel worker threads.  In fact, (1) is being
        // executed on all threads, as can be seen from the
        // output.

        Console.WriteLine("Expected thread IDs: {0}",
                          FormatItems(expectedThreadIds));
        Console.WriteLine("Found thread IDs: {0}",
                          FormatItems(threadIds.Distinct()));
    }
}
```

Example output I get is:

```
Expected thread IDs: [1]
Found thread IDs: [7;4;8;6;11;5;10;9]
```

Comment: You could foreach over the enumerable you get in (1) and spawn worker tasks within the loop. Await all tasks at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Asad, I am not sure if that would enable me to control the degree of parallelism.  Would it?  Perhaps if you could give more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward (although perhaps not as concise) if you abandon PLINQ and just use the Task Parallel Library explicitly:

```
// Limits the parallelism of the "expensive task"
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(8);

var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
    .Select(x => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    .Select(async x =>
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        var result = await Task.Run(() => Tuple.Create(x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        semaphore.Release();

        return result;
    });

return Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;
```

Note that I'm using `Tuple.Create` to record both the thread ID coming from the main thread and the thread ID coming from the spawned task. From my test, the former is always the same for every tuple, while the latter varies, which is as it should be.

The semaphore makes sure that the degree of parallelism never goes above 8 (although with the inexpensive task of creating a tuple this isn't very likely anyway). If you get to 8, any new tasks will wait until there's spots available on the semaphore.

Comment: This is really nice.  I especially like your use of a semaphore here.  I was definitely *not* wedded to PLINQ... let just make sure this works in my code tomorrow then I will accept the answer

Comment: The only potential snag I see here is that the output is non-streaming.  Not necessarily a huge problem---this is essentially a data reduction problem, so the output is much smaller and can be held in memory at one time.  Just curious if there might be a way to restore the streaming behavior.  I am thinking about it.

Comment: @DavidAlexander By "streaming", do you mean you want the results as they complete?

Comment: By streaming, I mean that I want to be able to get answers from the output before the entirety of the output is computed.  (However, note that I want to retain the original ordering; so I want to wait on the first answer, then the next answer...).  The solution above uses WhenAll, which waits until all tasks or completed.

Comment: In that case, remove the `WhenAll`, and use `foreach(var t in tasks) var result = await t;`. I should make it clear that this doesn't affect the order in which tasks are actually completed, and as far as I know there is no way to control this.

Comment: Thank you @Asad, you answered my question.  I may have a follow on question but I think I will open a new question if so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `OffloadQueryEnumeration` method below, which ensures that the enumeration of the source sequence will occur on the same thread that enumerates the resulting `IEnumerable<TResult>`. The `querySelector` is a delegate that converts a proxy of the source sequence to a [`ParallelQuery<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1). This query is enumerated internally on a `ThreadPool` thread, but the output values are surfaced back on the current thread.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates the source sequence on the current thread, and enumerates
/// the projected query on a ThreadPool thread.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OffloadQueryEnumeration<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> querySelector)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(querySelector);
    object locker = new();
    (TSource Value, bool HasValue) input = default; bool inputCompleted = false;
    (TResult Value, bool HasValue) output = default; bool outputCompleted = false;
    using IEnumerator<TSource> sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerable<TSource> GetSourceProxy()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TSource sourceItem;
            lock (locker)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (inputCompleted || outputCompleted) yield break;
                    if (input.HasValue) break;
                    Monitor.Wait(locker);
                }
                sourceItem = input.Value;
                input = default; Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
            }
            yield return sourceItem;
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<TResult> query = querySelector(GetSourceProxy());
    Task outputReaderTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (TResult result in query)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (outputCompleted) return;
                        if (!output.HasValue) break;
                        Monitor.Wait(locker);
                    }
                    output = (result, true); Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (locker) { outputCompleted = true; Monitor.PulseAll(locker); }
        }
    });

    // Main loop
    List<Exception> exceptions = new();
    while (true)
    {
        TResult resultItem;
        lock (locker)
        {
            // Inner loop
            while (true)
            {
                if (output.HasValue)
                {
                    resultItem = output.Value;
                    output = default; Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
                    goto yieldResult;
                }
                if (outputCompleted) goto exitMainLoop;
                if (!inputCompleted && !input.HasValue)
                {
                    // Fill the empty input slot, by reading the enumerator.
                    try
                    {
                        if (sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
                            input = (sourceEnumerator.Current, true);
                        else
                            inputCompleted = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                        inputCompleted = true;
                    }
                    Monitor.PulseAll(locker); continue;
                }
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
            }
        }
    yieldResult:
        bool yieldOK = false;
        try { yield return resultItem; yieldOK = true; }
        finally
        {
            if (!yieldOK)
            {
                // The consumer stopped enumerating prematurely
                lock (locker) { outputCompleted = true; Monitor.PulseAll(locker); }
                Task.WhenAny(outputReaderTask).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
exitMainLoop:

    // Propagate possible exceptions
    try { outputReaderTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { throw; }
    catch (AggregateException aex) { exceptions.AddRange(aex.InnerExceptions); }

    if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

This method uses the [`Monitor.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.wait)/[`Monitor.Pulse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.pulse) mechanism ([tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse)), in order to synchronize the transfer of the values from the one thread to the other.

Usage example:

```
int[] threadIds = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 1000)
    .Select(x => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    .OffloadQueryEnumeration(proxy => proxy
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(8)
        .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
        .Select(x => x)
    )
    .ToArray();
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSedfD).

The `OffloadQueryEnumeration` is a significantly intricate method. It is jungling non-stop three threads:

1. The current thread that both enumerates the `source` sequence, and consumes the PLINQ-generated elements, alternating between the two operations.
2. The `ThreadPool` thread (`outputReaderTask`) that enumerates the PLINQ-generated sequence.
3. The worker thread that is tasked by the PLINQ machinery to fetch the next item from the `GetSourceProxy()` iterator. This thread is not the same all the time, but at any given moment only one worker thread at most is assigned this task.

So lots of things are going on, and there are lots of opportunities for hidden bugs to pass undetected. This is the kind of API that would require writing a dozen of tests, to assert the correctness of the numerous possible scenarios (for example failure in the source sequence, failure in the PLINQ operators, failure in the consumer, cancellation, abandoned enumeration etc). I have tested manually some of these scenarios, but I haven't written any tests, so use this method with caution.